# Boost-python with Vigra and registerConverters()

Tags: numpy, boost-python

Does someone know what's the point of using registerConverters? See code below.

```
NumpyAnyArray test(NumpyArray<2, double > A, NumpyArray<2, double > B)
{
    MultiArrayShape<2>::type volumeShape(A.shape()[0], A.shape()[1]);
    B.reshape(volumeShape);
    B=A;
    B*=5;
    B(0,0)=1;
    B(1,1)=9;
    std::cerr<<A.shape()<<" "<<A.shape()[0]<<" "<<A.shape()[1]<<"\n";
    B(A.shape()[0]-1,0)=2;
    B(0,A.shape()[1]-1)=3;
    return B;
}
// Expose classes and methods to Python
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(cppinterface) {
    using namespace boost::python;
    using namespace vigra;
    import_vigranumpy();

    def("test", registerConverters(&test),(arg("A"), arg("B") = object())  );
}
```

Comment: Code snippet it taken from: http://www.blablub.org/?q=node/9

Answer (score 2):

Based on the Vigra [implementation](https://github.com/ukoethe/vigra/blob/c50de8a9a8371daa915736524c69f10e76ae9f14/include/vigra/numpy_array_converters.hxx#L165-L170), the `vigra::registerConverters()` is a convenience function used to register to-Python and from-Python converters for [`vigra::NumpyArray`](http://ukoethe.github.io/vigra/doc/vigra/classvigra_1_1NumpyArray.html) and [`vigra::MultiArrayView`](http://ukoethe.github.io/vigra/doc/vigra/classvigra_1_1MultiArrayView.html) types to NumPy's [`PyArrayObject`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.types-and-structures.html#PyArrayObject) types.

When providing seamless interoperability between C++ and Python, one often finds the need to register automatic type converters.  In this case, `registerConverters()` registers converters between Vigra arrays to NumPy arrays, rather than requiring Python users to use Vigra arrays.  In Boost.Python, converter registration operates on types, not templates.  Hence, converters must be registered for each type resulting from an instantiation of the Vigra template arrays.  With the use of meta-programming, `registerConverters()` reduces much of the boilerplate code that would normally be required for converter registration by decomposing the provided function signature into a type-list, then iterating over the list, conditionally registering converters for `NumpyArray` and `MultiArayView` types.

For more information on automatic converters, consider reading the Boost.Python [FAQ](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/python/doc/v2/faq.html#custom_string) example on how to register to-Python and from-Python converters.

Answer (score 0):

`registerConverters` are required to correctly cast c++ types such as int,short,char,etc.. to numpy types np.int32, np.int16, np.int8, ..